# Add fullscreen view as subview of view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to make a view1 that I can add as a subview to my view controller that covers the whole screen. Then inside view1 I want to place a 100x100 view2 in the center.

How can I do this with swift? (not storyboard). I want to create a stand alone uiview class, not just a variable inside the view controller.

I want to make view1 userInteractionDisabled.

Answer (score 1):

As you want stand alone uiview class, for two views make two classes. Thus modulating the code better, as following:

```
class TypeOneView: UIView {

  convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    // more ui customization
    backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    // add more customization if you want
  }

}

class TypeTwoView: UIView {

  convenience init(_ width: Double,_ height: Double) {
    let fullScreenHeight = Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    let fullScreenWidth = Double(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    self.init(frame: CGRect(x: (fullScreenWidth/2) - (width/2), y: (fullScreenHeight/2) - (height/2), width: width, height: width))
    // additional ui customization
    backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    // add more customization if you want
  }
}
```

Then instantiate and add these views as subview in your target view controller class as:

```
    let view1 = TypeOneView()
    let view2 = TypeTwoView(100.0, 100.0)
    view.addSubview(view1)
    view.addSubview(view2)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: view2)
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var view1:UIView!
var view2:UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view1.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.view.addSubview(view1)

    view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    view1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view1.addSubview(view2)

    view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    view2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view1.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view1.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. It would be something like this

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addMySubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        addMySubviews()
    }

    func addMySubviews() {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(view)
        leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(view.topAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
        bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(view.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true

        let view100x100 = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        view100x100.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(view100x100)

        view100x100.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(centerXAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
        view100x100.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(centerYAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
        view100x100.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        view100x100.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Use as mentioned below:

```
let myView = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 275, height: 600))
```

OR

```
let myView = MyView(frame: view.frame)
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(myView)

myView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
myView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(view.topAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
myView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
myView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(view.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
```